# Does light have light for itself? Is it really a ray or wave? Or more like a cluster of something ? (Only based on visible light)

Tags: optics, quantum-optics

During the observation of a laser light (not really laser) we kind of see a ray of light does it mean that every point on light itself is reflecting some other light into our eyes so that we are able to view that path of laser light?  (Only based on visible light I did not take any other rays such as gamma rays,...into account)

Comment: the laser "ray" would be invisible in a vacuum

Answer (score 4):

The rays you see are due to scattering of light from matter in the beam. It's usually dust, smoke, or mist that does the scattering.